# How do you sort a RealmList or RealmResult by distance?

Tags: android, sorting, realm

Given a [RealmObject](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html) that has the fields `latitude` and `longitude` and you have a RealmList or a RealmResult of such objects. How do you sort by distance by for example your current [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)?.

Ideas that have sprung to mind are:

1. Add a field `calculatedDistance`, iterate over all objects and set it. The problem with this approach is that the next time you call [copyToRealmOrUpdate(..)](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-) you'll overwrite this field with null.
2. Call Collections.sort(...) on the list or result with my own custom [Comparator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html) but I can't find it documented anywhere the behavior of a managed RealmList or RealmResult when they're sorted by "outsiders".
3. Do a really advanced query using [groupings](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#beginGroup--) and [between(..)](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#between-java.lang.String-float-float-) etc - but I can't come up with a good idea.

Anyone on Android found a good solution?

Comment: All I know is that [RealmGeoPoint](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1772) is on the Roadmap, but not exactly a priority as far as I know. There's a swift solution linked there, but I really don't get Swift.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks, I added my vote. I would really like to find a solution in the mean time. I looked at the Swift code, and it uses extensions which we don't have an equivalent for in Java land I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this really requires Geo spatial support to work in any efficient manner.

Right now I think your best bet is copying the data out of Realm and do manual processing in a worker thread.

If you implement it in a HandlerThread you can do something like this

```
RealmResults<City> results = realm.where(City.class).findAllAsync();
results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Results<City>>() {
  @Override
  public void onChange(RealmResults<City> cities) {
    List<City> standaloneCities = realm.copyFromRealm(cities);
    doManualSorting(standaloneCities);
    sendToUiThread(standaloneCities);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Christain Melchior , I have followed the same to sort my search result for 30K data but the UI freeze at real.copyFromRealm(cities. Your prompt response to this will be greatly appreciated, thanks