# Realm Custom Sort throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, realm

Using Realm for Android and I have a custom sort which throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Replacing and element is not supported

So, I have a piece of data that I need to sort after I have retreived it from a Realm database, so it is sitting in a List collection like this:

```
Collections.sort(stores, new DistanceComparator(currentLocation));
```

The DistanceComparator looks like this:

```
public class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Restaurant> {
    private Location currentLocation;

    public DistanceComparator(Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
    }

    public int compare(RealmObject c1, RealmObject c2) {
        if ((LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c1.getLocation()))
            == (LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c2.getLocation()))) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if ((LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c1.getLocation()))
            < (LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c2.getLocation()))) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the sort, I am getting a:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Replacing and element is not supported.                                                                              
    at io.realm.RealmResults$RealmResultsListIterator.set(RealmResults.java:868)
    at io.realm.RealmResults$RealmResultsListIterator.set(RealmResults.java:799)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:247)
```

I cannot perform the sort within Realm due to the transient nature of the data.

Can you not perform a basic sort against a collection that happen to have Realm data or do I need to add some sort of annotation in the class that is a RealmObject in order to perform this type of sort?

I did take a look at this question and that is my fallback if this will not work: [How do you sort a RealmList or RealmResult by distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733526/how-do-you-sort-a-realmlist-or-realmresult-by-distance)

Comment: Well you can either set up the sort as a sort condition for a field in the RealmObject (`findAllSorted("distance", Sort.ASCENDING)`) or you'll need to copy out all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform custom sorting on `RealmResult`. You'll have to copy your results to an unmanaged `List` and work with it instead of the realm results.

```
List<ModelMyFlirtsItem> storesList = realm.copyFromRealm(stores);
Collections.sort(storesList, new DistanceComparator(currentLocation));
```

Comment: So, in other words, the backup plan which was answered in the Stack Overflow link I mentioned. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I wonder, wouldn't List change its own size, if some object will be removed from realm? or it will be still in the list, just not valid? or there will be null?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider moving the value evaluated by `LocationUtil` to be part of the RealmObject itself, and do the sort by Realm.

```
public int compare(RealmObject c1, RealmObject c2) {
    if ((LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c1.getLocation()))
        == (LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c2.getLocation()))) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c1.getLocation()))
        < (LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(c2.getLocation()))) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

could be

```
public class RealmObject extends RealmObject {
    private Integer distance;
    private Location location;

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        if(location == null) {
            this.distance = null;
        } else {
            this.distance = LocationUtil.calculateSomeValue(location);
        }
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Then

```
RealmResults<RealmObject> results = realm.where(RealmObject.class).findAllSorted("distance", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: (works version `0.88.0` and above, but who on earth works with 0.87.5 and below lately? Realm is at `3.0.0`)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work because I would have to execute setLocation within a transaction which is not possible where the code is being processed.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. `copyFromRealm()` it is, then

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem for using sorting in `RealmResults`. I resolved it just using the `Realm`'s native `.sort()` function. For example -

```
RealmResult<Location> stores......;
 .......
 .......
 stores.sort(new DistanceComparator(currentLocation));
```